# Can I control which workspace/windows I’m using to open a file from an external terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In most time vscode used workspace to mange files and folders it opened, just like most IDE. But for cases I do things in an terminal a lot, and need to “adhocly” open a file, edit and save it, and continue my task on the terminal. Situations like this currently seems do not work perfectly with vscode.

For example:

I opened a workspace A and a workspace B. From workspace A I switch to an external terminal and run “ps aux| code -”. Then it will open the result in workspace A. Then for some reason I switch to workspace B, and then I switch to the external terminal and run “curl http://some_rest_api|code -r-“, then the result is open in workspace B. Continuing things like these make my vscode workspaces quite a mess.